# gcloud.run.deploy secret is not a valid secret name

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a cloud app to Google Cloud Run, but am unable to set some secrets that have been already created and added to the Secrets Manager for the project & giving the appropriate permissions. The CLI is unable to find the corresponding secret. The same secret works fine if I try to deploy from the Cloud Run UI by setting a reference to the secret.

My command:

```
gcloud run deploy app-1 --image=us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/app-1/app/app-1:latest  --region=us-east1  --service-account=vertex-ai-consumer@app-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com  --allow-unauthenticated --set-secrets="GOOGLE_API_KEY=projects/app-1/secrets/GOOGLE_API_KEY:latest"
```

gives the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) 'projects/app-1/secrets/GOOGLE_API_KEY' is not a valid secret name.
```

This is the error for all secrets I have defined

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work by removing the full path reference to the secret, i.e. changing the command to:

```
gcloud run deploy app-1 --image=us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/app-1/app/app-1:latest  --region=us-east1  --service-account=vertex-ai-consumer@app-1.iam.gserviceaccount.com  --allow-unauthenticated --set-secrets="GOOGLE_API_KEY=GOOGLE_API_KEY:latest"
```

Comment: I get this error - ```gcloud crashed (ValueError): Invalid secret path 'projects/<project-id>/secrets/<secret-name>' in annotation``` when I do this. Any ideas on what could be wrong ?